# Reputation not appearing on username flyout

Tags: support, reputation

The daily, weekly and month reputation on not appearing on either the StackOverflow or the Meta flyout that appears when hovering over the username.

[image]

Across the board everything is zero. I am seeing this in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Happy July 1st. :)

Comment: @animuson I don't like that present! :)

Comment: UTC time is a harsh mistress

Comment: @ben yes I believe that threw me off. Doh!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well midnight happened to start a new day, a new week, and a new month all at the same time.

- New day every night, duh. It's a new day.
- The day just changed to Sunday, so that starts a new week.
- It's the first of the month, so that start a new month.

So all the values *should* have reset to 0. Oh, they have.

[image: Cool Beans]

Comment: Yes I do feel especially dumb right now. I guess that is what happens after being in 113 degree heat all day. My brain is toast.

Comment: -1 None of your Beans have freehand mustaches.