# Weekly reputation is not shown correctly

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation not appearing on username flyout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138291/reputation-not-appearing-on-username-flyout)

I have gained reputation through last week on [SO](http://www.stackoverflow.com), but they don't appear on my profile menu. Is this a bug? (the reputation of week is zero)

[image]

Comment: A new week just started. You have no reputation gains in this week.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `week` and `month` cumulative totals shown in that overview are not referring to the last 7 or 30 days, but to the calendar week and month. Stack Exchange weeks start on Sunday, and the month on the first day of the calendar month.

Since you have yet to [gain reputation today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69537/meysam?tab=reputation) your total for this week is still 0.